# Is there a way to define at which level of a categorical variable the correlation between two continuous variables is higher?

Tags: r, statistics, correlation

I have three different variables:

- two continuous variables
- one categorical variables with 23 levels

What I want to know is the level of the categorical variable in which the correlation between the two continuous variables is higher. Is there a way to do it in R?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Group by the categorical variable.  Calculate the within-group correlation between the continuous variables.  Determine which group produces the highest correlation.  What am I missing?  Perhaps your question would have been clearer if you had provided a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you're looking for conceptual answer, post it on Cross Validated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Here it seems you're looking for sample code, sharing reproducible code can get you clear responses of possible approaches.